# PHP email script just opens PHP file

Tags: php, html, linux, forms, apache

I'm hosting a website on a Linux server, running Ubuntu Server 11.04 (32 bit). The web server is Apache. One of the pages on the site has a form with the submit linking to a PHP email script. Form code:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="email.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="name" class="textbox"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="email" class="textbox"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="message_box_header">Describe your problem:<br /></div>
<textarea class="textbox"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" id="submit" />
</form>
```

The Linux server has the most up to date version of sendmail. I don't know PHP well at all and got the script pre-written, so I imagine my problem is probably there. I replaced the website/emails with dummy ones, for privacy. Here's email.php:

```
<?php
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  mail( "myemail@gmail.com", "Form Data",
    $message, "From: $email" );
  header( "Location: http://mywebsite.com" );
?>
```

When I click the submit button on the actual website, it just downloads email.php.

Comment: Allow it to download and then open the file. If you see PHP code then PHP is not being interpreted on your server. So it would be a configuration issue or possible a host that for some odd reason does not have PHP.

Comment: Do you have any other PHP on the site?
Try to omit the `?>` at the end and add `exit;` to the end.

Comment: **Side note:** use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` for post data, and use `$_GET` for get data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure PHP is actually installed on your server (that should be the first thing you do, following cryptic's instructions).

If it is installed, and you're still having the problem, add this to your apache config (`.htaccess`):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: Hmm. Installed PHP5 and appended that line to httpd.conf and still no change. So if the site is just downloading the script as is, that's definitely a problem in the server, and not (necessarily) in the script?

Comment: Very most probably a server issue. When you open the downloaded file with a text editor, do you see PHP code or just HTML?

Comment: Yes. It's the same file, 'email.php'.

Comment: Can you try this in your `httpd.conf`? `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` Also, don't forget to restart Apache when you edit `httpd.conf`

Comment: Right. That restart fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `name` attribute of your input fields instead of `id`. Otherwise no data is sent. If the file is being downloaded this is a configuration error of the webserver not the script.

Answer (score 0):

update your package manger by running this command:

```
apt-get update
```

and install `mod_fcgid` and `php5-cgi` by running this command:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
```

`mod_fcgid` will be enabled by installer otherwise run this command to enable it:

```
a2enmod fcgid
```

now you can add these pre configed lines to your apache config file:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FcgidIOTimeout 3600
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000 
FcgidMaxRequestLen 52428800
FcgidConnectTimeout 3600
FcgidMaxProcesses 12
FcgidOutputBufferSize 64
FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidWrapper /usr/bin/php-cgi .php
```

your apache config file may be available at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

for more information about fast cgi handler see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html